# Prove by induction $2^n \geq n^3 \ \ \forall n\geq 10 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

Prove by induction $2^n \geq n^3 \ \ \forall n\geq 10 $

I did these steps:

1. **Basis step**
   $$P(10): \ \ 1024 \geq 1000 \ (True)$$
2. **Inductive step**
   $$P(n) \implies P(n+1) \\P(n+1) = 2^{n+1} \geq (n+1)^3$$
   so $$2^n \geq n^3 \\ 2^n \cdot 2 \geq n^3  \cdot 2 \\ 2^{n+1} \geq 2n^3 \\ 2^{n+1} \geq (n+1)^3$$
   taking advantage of the fact that $(n+1)^3 \geq 2n^3$ and less than $2^{n+1}$.

does this demonstration work?

I know there's a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995387/prove-using-induction-tricky-one?rq=1) but the solution is different, I want to know if my demonstration is valid as well.

Comment: [Another related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772026/721644).

Comment: It is the other way round. For $n \geq 4, (n+1)^3 \leq 2n^3$. So that obviously shows that $2^{n+1} \geq 2n^3 \geq (n+1)^3$. But if you are claiming it, you need to show why $2n^3 \geq (n+1)^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so $$2^n \geq n^3 \\ 2^n \cdot 2 \geq n^3  \cdot 2 \\ 2^{n+1} \geq 2n^3 \\ 2^{n+1} \geq (n+1)^3$$
> taking advantage of the fact that $(n+1)^3 \geq 2n^3$ and less than $2^{n+1}$.

> does this demonstration work?

No, your analysis (in and of itself) hasn't shown that 
$(n+1)^3 \leq 2^{n+1}$, assuming that I am not overlooking anything.  This is what you are trying to prove.

The easy way, is:

after noting that $2^{10} > 10^3$, and assuming that $2^n > n^3$, simply note that for $n \geq 10$,

$$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^3 < 2. \tag1$$

Note that $2^{1/3} > 1.25$, and for $n \geq 10, \frac{n+1}{n} < 1.25$.

This justifies equation (1) above.

Thus:

$$2^{n+1} = 2 \times 2^n > 2 \times n^3 > \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^3 \times n^3 = (n+1)^3.$$

Comment: I didn't understand how you found $$ [\frac{n+1}{n}]^3 $$ because 'n' can be simplified with  $n^3$?

Comment: @LorisSimonetti I asked myself: when starting with the inequality $$2^n > n^3$$ and attempting to use that to prove that $$2^{(n+1)} > (n+1)^3,$$ what is happening to each side of the inequality?  The LHS is being multiplied by $2$ and the RHS is being multiplied by $\left[\frac{n+1}{n}\right]^3.$

Comment: After applying the induction hypothesis, you want that $2n^3$ to be greater than $(n+1)^3$

Comment: @jjagmath which is equivalent to what I proved, which is that $$2 > \left[\frac{n+1}{n}\right]^3.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Ok, got it! thanks.

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I was answering to Loris, but you answered first

Answer (score 1):

You already proved the base case

Now suppose that $n^3\le 2^n$  is true and

let's prove it for $n+1$

$(n+1)^3=n^3+\left(3n^2+3n+1\right)\tag{1}<\ldots$

for $n\ge 4$ we have $3n^2+3n+1 < n^3$ indeed, adding $n^3$ to both sides we get

$n^3+3 n^2+3 n+1<n^3+n^3\to (n+1)^3<2n^3\to n+1<n\sqrt[3]{2}\to n(\sqrt[3]{2}-1)>1\to n>\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}-1}\approx 3.8$

continue $(1)$ $$\ldots<n^3+n^3\le 2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$$

Comment: You are right! I was thinking to the simplest way to prove it @MathLover

Comment: @MathLover I think I did it :)