# Prove the sequence $x_n = \frac{2^n}{n^2}$ is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having difficulties proving the sequence  $x_n = \frac{2^n}{n^2}$ is unbounded.

I can prove it is monotone from some term, but I don't know if it is necessary:

$\frac{2^n}{n^2}$ v $\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n + 1)^2}$

After transformations I get:

$\frac{2^n}{n^2}$ < $\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n + 1)^2}$, when $n > 1 + \sqrt{2}$

However, when I am trying to prove by contradiction that the sequence is unbounded, I get:

$\frac{2^n}{n^2} < M$

$n < log_2 (M*n^2)$

And after that I can only get the initial statement and I do not know how to proceed. Can someone show me what to do next? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)? Try using it for $2^n=(1+1)^n$ ...

Comment: @rtybase  Actually yes, can we use it to prove unboudness?

Comment: Of course, because for sufficiently large $n$'s $$(1+1)^n > 1 + n + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$$

Comment: More generally: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial

Comment: The sequence is bounded from below by $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{2}{(\frac{n+1}{n})^2}$ and the ratio approximates 2 for big $n$.  Therefore the sequence is not bounded, since for sufficiently big $n$, $x_{n+1} \approx 2 x_n$

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, but could you please tell me how I prove it more formally. Like, can I say, that since for any number $M$ ($x_n < M$) there exists $k$, such that $2^k * x_n > M$, the sequence is unbounded. Or is it not enough?

Comment: Since $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is an increasing sequence and converges to $2$ we can find and $M$ such that $x_{n+1} \geq \frac{3}{2} x_n$ for every $n > M$. Therefore $x_n \geq \frac{3}{2}^{n-M} x_M$ for every $n > M$ and the sequence is clearly not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative we can easily prove by induction that $2^n\ge n^3$ then

$$x_n = \frac{2^n}{n^2}\ge \frac{n^3}{n^2}=n$$

which is clearly unbounded.

Refer to the related:

- [Prove using Induction | Tricky one!](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1995387/505767)
- [Use induction to prove that $2^n \gt n^3$ for every integer $n \ge 10$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772026/505767)